# Как получить(импортировать) входные данные? Яндекс Практикум

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, импорт

[image: Как обработать данные из input.txt]
Как (импортировать, получить доступ) к input.txt на скриншоте.
Объясните пожалуйста как работать с входными данными из файла!! Пишу на JS. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

html `<input id="myInput" type="file">`

```
function download ( text ) {
  let a = document . createElement ('a');
  a . download = 'output.txt';
  a . href = URL . createObjectURL ( new Blob ([ text ],{ type: 'text/plain'}));
  a . click ();
}
function myWork ( input ){ 
     let output = input . slice ( 0 , 9 );
     //тут собственно создаем output из input, строчка выше примера ради.
     download ( output );
}
document . getElementById ('myInput'). onchange = function (){
    const reader = new FileReader ();
    reader . onload = function ({ target }){
         myWork ( target . result );
    };
    reader . readAsText ( document . getElementById ('myInput'). files [ 0 ]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но, а нет способа попроще, скажем импортировать этот файл как-то и сразу загнать значения в функцию?

Comment: есть, можно подключить скрипт <script src="/magic.js"></script> а в нем что-то вроде             ````var myImport = 'text'```` myImport будет доступен в остальном контексте, но так-то можно было и сразу строку объявить =)

Comment: Но у меня не доступа в HTML только одно текстовое поле в котором как-то надо получить доступ к этому файлу. Я имел в виду что нужно сделать чтобы входные данные получить из файла. Как их импортировать или что нужно импортировать чтобы без HTML получить к ним доступ и работать с ними?